# Fixing mirrored bones rotation.

Tags: rigging

[image]

[image]

So I know that after mirroring in the rigs, I have to fix the rotation problem of the left side. So I selected the original bones and had x-axis mirroring checked. Pressed ctrl+R to rotate the mesh. However, it seems that the rig just fliped itself again, which I had no idea of what's causing it.
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: afair, if your bones are named in a way that blender understands "sides", like arm.R and arm.L many tools use that information to do "mirrored" things more properly, could it be that? see http://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/armatures/editing/properties.html#naming-bones

Comment: Thank you. Well, I did name them correctly, so the problem still exists.